# Interactive Legend for Flex Mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, touch, legend

I've followed [this awesome tutorial](http://blog.flexmp.com/2008/03/10/interactive-charting-legend-to-select-which-series-to-display/) for creating an interactive legend to hide and display a chart series.

The problem is the legend items do not react to touch events for mobile.

I've tried all of these.

```
itemMouseDown="clickLegend(event)"  itemMouseOver="clickLegend(event)" itemMouseUp="clickLegend(event)"
                       itemClick="myLegend_itemClickHandler(event)"
```

How do I determine which legend item was touched?   Should I overlay invisible buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a TOUCH_TAP event listener to each legend item, as displayed in the `function MyLegendItem()` for mouse down event. Just add this line to the constructor:

```
addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,handleEvent);
```

You will have to change the event type on `handleEvent` declaration to `Event` instead of `MouseEvent`, because `TouchEvent` and `MouseEvent` are not directly related.

Also, the syntax you've tried is not AS3, but rather JS or AS1 instead. You should first search for proper AS3 syntax to try.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer.  I think it should be working.  I added this function:  private function handleTouchEvent(event:TouchEvent):void{
  selected=!_selected; 
  trace('touch event on myLegendItem');
 }

I also added addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,handleTouchEvent); inside MyLegendItem().   Still not getting the trace message back.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do they change selected state? If not, you might need to configure touch screen to use taps, not gestures. Call `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;` in your main app. By the way, if you're not planning to uise multitouch at all, you can do `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.NONE;` and get by with mouse events without any touch events involved.

Comment: Another great suggestion!  But it is still not changing state or tracing the message.  I thought for sure you had it solved.

Comment: Hmm, if this doesn't solve the problem, seek elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing effort!  I really appreciate it.  I am working on an awesome data app.  I think I will have to use invisible buttons overlaid on top of the legend.   Thanks for trying.  Are you able to get it to work in a demo app?

Comment: @Vesper:  The syntax looks like mxml fragments to me.

Comment: @Brian If that's MXML, he should include the mx:stuff wrapping. Sadly I'm inept in MXML, I can do things in AS3 but not in meta-languages (yet).

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I ended up overlaying buttons on top.